# Unable to show images of Python code?

Tags: python, css, twitter-bootstrap-4

Is there some unwritten rule that you are not allowed to show images of Python code on Github websites? I tried to upload images in this manner, however, it doesn't work. Images are png and source linked appropriately.

https://eclecticexistential.github.io/

Comment: How would "they" know it's an image of code? (I mean, wow – Stack Overflow would be interested!)

Comment: "It doesn't work"  What happens?

Comment: PatrickHaugh is right. [We need information to help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I realized how asinine the thought was before I asked it, however, the file location was the same as the others and obviously the only difference was that it was python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your repository [here](https://github.com/eclecticexistential/eclecticexistential.github.io), at [index.html](https://github.com/eclecticexistential/eclecticexistential.github.io/blob/master/index.html)  you reference the image as `imgs/pythonCode.png` whereas it is named `imgs/pythonCode.PNG` with capitals. I would recommend renaming the `.PNG` into `.png`. I confirmed this by changing the source in dev tools

[image: screen shot of website]

This is also the case for the two images on your `python.html` page.

Comment: Actually, yes, it did. Unclear as to why those Python images needed to be capitalized since the others did not. Nevertheless, I appreciate the assistance.